# How to solve the recurrence relation $G(k) = 2^{(1.5)\cdot 2^k}G(k-1) + \left(2 ^{3 \cdot (2^k)}\right)\left(2 ^{ (2k)}\right) \cdot k$

Tags: recurrence-relations

$G(k) = 2^{(1.5)\cdot 2^k}G(k-1) + \left(2 ^{3 \cdot (2^k)}\right)\left(2 ^{ (2k)}\right) \cdot k$

G(1) = c

I could not get any development that converged into anything. Can you please help to how to start?

**EDIT**:

I have started with other recurrence relation  $T(n) = n^{\frac{3}{2}}T \left(n^{\frac{1}{2}} \right) + n^3 \log^2(n)\log(\log(n))$ and got G(k) after 2 variable replacements. now need to continue with G(k) but I'm stuck here

Comment: Seems like follow up to [How to solve the recurrence relation: $T(n) = n^{\frac{3}{2}}T \left(n^{\frac{1}{2}} \right) + n^3 \log^2(n)\log(\log(n))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3133583)

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear recurrence with solution $G(k) = G_h(k)+G_p(k)$ with

$$
G_h(k)- 2^{\frac 32 2^k}G_h(k-1)=0\\
G_p(k)- 2^{\frac 32 2^k}G_p(k-1)=2^{3\times 2^k}2^{2k}k\\
$$

for the homogeneous term we have

$$
G_h(k) = C_0 8^{2^k}
$$

now making

$$
G_p(k) = C_0(k) 8^{2^k}
$$

we have after substitution

$$
C_0(k) -C_0(k-1) = 2^{2k} k
$$

which has as solution

$$
C_0(k) = \frac 49\left(1+2^{2k}(3k-1)\right)
$$

hence

$$
G(k) = C_0 8^{2^k}+\frac 49\left(1+2^{2k}(3k-1)\right)8^{2^k}
$$

Comment: Please. Be aware of the committed typo now corrected.